# What screwdriver to tighten bottom rMBP screws?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

What screwdriver to buy to tighten bottom screws on MacBook Pro Retina?

Based on search, it seams to be pentalobe flower. But what are dimensions? Are there any variances?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest iFixit's [MacBook Pro and Air 5-Point Pentalobe Screwdriver](http://www.ifixit.com/Tools/MacBook-Pro-and-Air-5-Point-Pentalobe-Screwdriver/IF145-090).

Comment: Are you sure - do you have rMBP? I googled this one also but when I compare the shape is different. The screws on rMBP looks like flower while this screwdriver shape looks like star. To be sure, I'd like to check dimensions too.

Comment: According to the product page, and iFixit's tear downs of *both* the [15"](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2012+Teardown/9462/1) and [13"](http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Retina+Display+Late+2012+Teardown/11225/1) late 2012 retina macs, this is the correct driver.

Comment: The image (especially the leftmost) definitely looks like a Torx screwdriver.  Maybe that also fits into and engages a pentalobe (and they sell it because Torx is fairly common while pentalobe is Apple smemi proprietary), but the shape is not a genuine pentalobe.

Comment: Sorry, I stand corrected.  Looked again and Torx is a 6-edge star.  Pretty likely that iFixit thing will do the job, even though it has a starry base form.